# SQL Server Management Studio register server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed the SQL Server Management Studio 18.12.1 and am trying to create a new database on my computer, but I can't register a server.

In the new server registration dialog box, my computer is not listed in the server name dropdown.  When I click browse for more, nothing is in the list of local servers. How do I add my computer to the list?  If I just type in the name of the computer, and try to connect, it fails. I get this error:  Testing the registered server failed.  Verify the server name, login credentials, and database, and then click Test again.

And ... SQL Server Configuration Manager is not listed in the Console Root Add/Remove Snap-in option.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install SQL Server as well?  It's a separate install from SSMS.

Comment: I figured that out after I posted my question.  Thank you!  :D